# Как сделать плавный переход при воспроизведении аудио discord python?

Tags: python, аудио, discord, discord.py

Есть 2 аудиофайла, первый воспроизводится сейчас и до конца аудио остается 2 секунды. Мне надо сделать плавный переход на другое аудио по такой схеме:

1. За 2 секунды до конца воспроизведентя аудио1 начинает воспроизводиться аудио2 с 0% громкости.
2. Аудио1 начинает затухать (постепенно уменьшается громкость до 0%)
3. Одновременно с пунктом 2 делается и этот пункт.
   Аудио2 начинает возрастать (постепенно увеличивается громкость до 100%)
4. После этого перехода в 2 секунды аудио2 воспроизводится как обычно.

Пробовал через FFmpegPCMAudio это сделать, но там нельзя воспроизводить 2 аудио одновременно (по крайней мере у меня не получилось).
Так вот. Как реализовать то, что описано выше?